# Disable “not ejected properly” warning (as only charging and not writing data)

Tags: macos, eject

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable “the disk was not ejected properly” message](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6078/disable-the-disk-was-not-ejected-properly-message)

Per [this blog post (not my blog post)](http://www.pcpro.co.uk/blogs/2011/01/07/shouted-down-by-the-apple-community/) how would you go about disabling the warning popup given that I know I'm not writing data so can't suffer any data loss?

I'd be satisfied with an answer that just disabled this warning across the board, but a more specific solution that could blacklist specific devices, or even better a "smart" way of only showing the popup if data has been written.

Comment: Can't be done.  And you should only get the warning if a disk is actually mounted, which leads me to believe you're not "just charging," even though you think you are.  You're still at risk.

Comment: The disk is mounted, but if no data has been added/removed/etc (at least not any I care about / have asked to be transferred) doesn't that mean I'm not at risk?

Comment: No.