# osx corrupts usb (exFAT) on restart

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb

So  I have this problem with OS X, when I restart my system and it has the USB drive connected (I forgot to unplug it because I know what OS X causes), it corrupts the drive (i.e., on next restart it can't read/mount the USB drive), now my solutions is go to a friend computer with windows and use "repair tool"... but this time seems like it won't work again... so how apple pays for >500Gb of information? (well just kidding I know they will not), so my questions are

1. How I stop OS X from being badass with USB disk (i.e. not corrupting them so that I need to remember to unplug it first).
2. How I recover/repair my files, this time my friend Windows seems not able to recover it.

BY the way, this corruption also happened if I disconnect directly the USB (which work on windows AFAIK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also posted your question 1 [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230698/disable-the-disk-check-when-reconnecting-an-improperly-disconnected-disk-to-os-x). If your disk is HFS formatted, here's a rumour [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230698/disable-the-disk-check-when-reconnecting-an-improperly-disconnected-disk-to-os-x) that you can just kill the process `fsck_hfs` and the disk reappears immediately (FSCK=file system consistency check). Next time I have a scan, I'll be looking for a `fsck_exfat` equivalent process to kill. [Disabling the write cache](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6108/disable-file-system-cache-for-usb-devices?rq=1) would reduce risk, but not prevent the scan - it doesn't on Windows, and there's still the risk the disk was disconnected during a non-cached write.

For your question 2, leave the disk connected to your Mac for a while. OS X runs the same repair process, it just does it silently. (Someone answered my identical question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/226623/repair-an-exfat-drive-on-mac-os-x-after-its-been-improperly-disconnected/227382).)

In my experience disconnection almost never actually causes corruption (Windows tells you if it finds an error, and I've never, ever seen it find one) - but a [flag](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/805-7228/6j6q7uf0d/index.html) `File System State` is set on the drive prompting the repair scan. On Debian, Ubuntu or Linux Mint, [this can be disabled](http://xmodulo.com/automatic-filesystem-checks-repair-linux.html) in `/etc/default/rcS`, on CentOS, `/etc/sysconfig/autofsck` - we need the OS X version..anyone?

Update: klanomath answered question two [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230698/disable-the-disk-check-when-reconnecting-an-improperly-disconnected-disk-to-os-x/230712#230712) - I'll report back once tested.