# Disable USB Write Caching by default

Tags: macos, usb, external-disk, mount

Is it possible to change OS X's USB filesystem mount behaviour to use the `noasync` flag to disable write caching?

The aim here is to allow USB devices to be safely removed without `eject` or `hdiutil unmount`, as opposed to

- Disabling `the disk was not ejected properly` warning (See [How do I disable this message: "the disk was not ejected properly"?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6078/how-do-i-disable-this-message-the-disk-was-not-ejected-properly))
- Manually running `mount` every time (See [Is it possible to disable write caching on a USB mass storage device on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/113019/is-it-possible-to-disable-write-caching-on-a-usb-mass-storage-device-on-mac-os-x))

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

In fact, at least with apfs, noasync isn't even an option:

`mount_apfs: unrecognized option 'noasync'`