# Disabling a specific system notification?

Tags: usb, notifications, power

My Macbook Air 13" (macOS 10.13.6) has a USB problem which triggers a warning notification every five minutes:

[image: USB Accessories Disabled]

Looking in the Console, I see lots of "overcurrent detected" warnings; testing the two USB ports shows that the left one seems dead while the right one works. Visually, the left port is fine; no schmutz that might be causing problems.

Clearly I'm going to have to replace the left USB port (actually the [I/O board)](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Air-13-Inch-Mid-2013-2017-I-O-Board/IF188-092?o=1), but in the meantime is there any way to disable this specific notification? (I really don't need both USB ports; if I could stop the messages I would probably skip fixing the hardware.)

**Edit:** I wasn't clear: these messages appear even when nothing is plugged into either USB port.

Comment: A message like that is considered important by apple and I don't think you can disable system messages like that without disabling the hardware that triggers the message.

Comment: Hey Daniel! Was there no device connected to either of the USB ports? Also can you check in activity monitor for `usbd` ?

Comment: @ankiiiiiii Nope: nothing plugged in. And, I'll check for `usbd`.

Comment: Hey @DanielGriscom, I think that your question is a possible duplicate of [How do I disable this message: "the disk was not ejected properly"?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6078/how-do-i-disable-this-message-the-disk-was-not-ejected-properly) If the answer below(which comes from the same question) answers your query, then it is confirmed. If it doesn't, you might need to differentiate between  the two.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii Unfortunately, the solution proposed disables **all** notifications, which is a bit heavy-handed. I need to try the proposed answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried...

> This applescript will close them for you. Paste it into Script Editor
>   and then Save as an application. Then grant access to that application
>   in (System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Accessibility) Then you
>   can use an application like ControlPlane
>   https://www.controlplaneapp.com/ to run the application on wake thus
>   closing them all automatically! ** Note: You will need to grant
>   Accessibility access to ControlPlane as well.

```
tell application "System Events"
tell process "NotificationCenter"
    set numwins to (count windows)
    repeat with i from numwins to 1 by -1
        tell window i
            set temp to value of static text 1
        end tell
        if temp contains "USB Accessories Disabled" then
            click button "Close" of window i
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
end tell
```

From [How do I disable this message: "the disk was not ejected properly"?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6078/how-do-i-disable-this-message-the-disk-was-not-ejected-properly)

This will need some tweaking to close the window you are looking for maybe a cron job or something similar but it might be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Obviously the OP will need to amend the code to change the string it's looking for to determine whether or not to close the window. Perhaps replacing *Disk Not Ejected Properly* with *USB Accessories Disabled*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I'll check whether it works soon. (And boy! do I hate AppleScript... it's right down there with Perl, although for very different reasons...)

Comment: Is ControlPlane still recommended? The website is not online anymore, and the github repo (https://github.com/dustinrue/ControlPlane) hasn't been updated for a couple of years and it looking for a maintainer.