# The "Disk Not Ejected Properly" notification will not go away on Mojave?

Tags: macos, mac, mojave, notifications

If I forgot to plug in my Mac to the power and came back a couple of hours later, it may show "Disk Not Ejected Properly" notifications (two of them on Mojave).

But the notification display a "Show" and clicking on it has no effect. Clicking on the notification has no effect. So these two notifications are blocking all the view of other window content because they always stay on top of every other window. (they are blocking the tabs of Google Chrome)

How can they be removed?  Or else I have to close most everything and restart the Mac, which is a pain just due to this bug.

Comment: It's extremely annoying. https://ibb.co/G0kjPQ1

Comment: At least I can run this applescript to get rid of most of them: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/310971/57681
I wonder if this works to prevent them: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/12701/57681

Answer (score 1):

The notification being there covering the screen and won't go away can be really troublesome.

It can be solved by moving the mouse to a "blank screen" hot corner. (set it up first).  And then when you wake the Mac, that notification can be dismissed.

So this is a solution, and would save Apple $27 / hour to hire a contractor to fix this bug in a day.